# Solenoid Example - Interesting group

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Consider the topological group(s) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)#Pathological_properties

This seems like an interesting and bizarre group. It is obviously not a Lie group and obviously not a manifold. However, I was wondering if it satisfies geometric properties like **local contractibility**? What about its **homology groups**? Is there a nice reference for the topological properties of this group?

Could anyone tell me more about this group? Thanks!

Comment: It's a $1$-dimensional continuum, and it's nowhere locally connected. As you noticed it's a topological group so it's homogeneous. Also there is no one Solenoid, it's a whole family of spaces depending on how we choose our parameters in the construction. As for other properties e.g. it can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It's also not path-connected, $\pi_n(X) = 0$ where $n\geq 2$ and $X$ is the Solenoid. Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3680875/476484).

Comment: @Jakobian What about things like being  absolute or euclidean neighborhood retracts? Is it simply connected? I think not, maybe $\pi_1(X)=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SomePerson the fundamental group based at any point is trivial, since path components of a solenoid are simply connected, but the solenoid is not path connected, it has continuum many path components. Solenoids are not absolute neighbourhoods retracts, this was proved by Borsuk iirc

Comment: Ah much easier, solenoids are not locally path connected, so they are not locally contractible and they cannot be ANRs